# Filter function not working for Date (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I've tried to filter an array by a set date

```
var di = new Date(this.state.date.slice(0, 4),
                  this.state.date.slice(5, 7),
                  this.state.date.slice(8, 10),
                  '10',
                  '00');
var result2 = result.filter(function(number) {
  return (number[2] == di)
});
```

But the result is an empty array (`result2`).

Below is a screenshot of `console.log(di)` and one element of the array -

[image]

Comment: empty array in result

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot compare two different objects in javascript using `==`
This will return `true` only comparing the same instance of an object.

To make Your code work you can try converting the dates to strings.

```
var result2 = result.filter(function(number) {
  return (number[2].toString() == di.toString())
});
```

or by using the .getTime() method of Date object

```
var result2 = result.filter(function(number) {
  return (number[2].getTime() == di.getTime())
});
```

Answer (score -3):

The first argument to the `filter` function is an array element, not the array itself, so it should be:

```
result.filter( function(el) { return (el == di); } );
```

Comment: Please be more specific, post a complete example, and try reading some documentation first.

Comment: @kenh it _is_ a complete example, you just didn't read it properly.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts `result` is not defined in his example, so it is not complete, in my opinion anyway. Also it is unclear what is being passed into `Date` constructor, because he doesn't show what `this.state.date` is.

Comment: @kjh what is passed into `Date()` is irrelevant since the `di` is logged, and the schema of an element in `result` _is_ in fact given, both in the screenshot.